# install phpmyadmin and sql

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I successfully installed MySQL, it runs perfectly. Then, I download and installed phpMyadmin, and somehow it does not work.　when i click the start button in the phpmyadmin control panel, it somehow shows the following. Does anyone know what is going on here ? Do i need to uninstall MySQL ? thanks a million.

```
10:21:41 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
10:21:41 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:21:41 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:21:41 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:21:41 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:21:41 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:21:41 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:21:41 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Any more errors in the error logs or Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: thanks for your help, Michelle. After click logs, it shows can not find the d:xampp\apache\logs\access.log  file

Comment: i shall mention that i have installed IIS (internet information services). Does this influence anything ? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anything in the Windows event log?

Comment: now, I uninstall another version of MySQL and uninstall Xampp, and install xampp again, and this time, mysql works and the Apache does not work. In the control panel of the Xampp, i got this:

Comment: 2:21:47 AM  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
2:21:47 AM  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
2:21:47 AM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
2:21:47 AM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:21:47 AM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:21:47 AM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:21:48 AM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:21:48 AM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
2:21:48 AM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: @Michelle, what suggestions do you have ?

Comment: The same suggestion as the error message; to look in the Windows Event Viewer.